# Simple SQL DAL for 4-5 queries

Tags: .net, sql, database

I have to gather data from a sql database to populate a ning map i am creating.  I only need data from one table in the database.  The table has company data in it, name country state, email, website, etc.

What is the best way to do this?  I am doing my bing map using .net so i was thinking of just gathering all my data in code behind in the .aspx.cs file.  Or would it be better to do a dataset?  I was thinking a dataset would be overkill for such a small amount of procedures.

Basically sql queries will look something like this

Populate a drop down with this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM Partners
```

On changing that drop down I will populate another drop down

```
SELECT DISTINCT State FROM Partner WHERE Country = @country
```

after that i will grab a bunch of company data from that country

Answer (score 1):

Using a full-blown ORM like EF, Linq2SQL or NHibernate is certainly possible, but IMO it's overkill if you really have only 4-5 queries.

I would use a Micro ORM like [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/), [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) or [PetaPoco](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/) for a simple task like this.
All of them are able to map SQL queries directly to lists of POCOs. Visit the links and take a look at the examples there.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Linq To Sql` or `ADO.NET Entity Framework`. they are both fit to rapid development of a data access layer. just create the stored procedures used to get the Data from the DB and create Linq To Sql class or Entity class in your IDE.

Links that can help:
[ADO.net entity framework-Stored procedures](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/12/17/ado-net-entity-framework-tools-stored-procedures.aspx)

[Linq to SQL-5 min overview](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoSQL5MinuteOverview.ashx)